# linkable tokens

Tags: algorithm-design, protocol-design

Is it possible for $n$ parties for each to perform operations $f_1$,$f_2$,...,$f_n$ (they can all be the same function) on $x$. Now, another party $A$ given all $n$ values of $f(x)$s should know they were performed on a single $x$. However, even if $A$ is given $x$ it can't determine if the $n$ parties performed the operation on $x$ or not ($Pr = 1/2$ for PPT).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to do this unless the operations $f_1, \dots, f_n$ themselves include a secret component. Otherwise $A$, given $x$, could just compute $f_i(x)$ for some $i$ and check if it matches the values provided by the other parties.

On the other hand, if the other parties are allowed to have some shared secret knowledge that $A$ doesn't have, then any [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (or, more generally, any privacy-preserving [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) should suffice.  Specifically, let all the operations $f_i$ be the same function $f(x) = \operatorname{PRF}_K(x)$, where $K$ is a secret key not known to $A$, and $\operatorname{PRF}$ is a keyed pseudorandom function family from which the participants select the specific instance $\operatorname{PRF}_K$ associated with the key $K$.  Since a PRF is deterministic, it is sufficient for $A$ to check whether or not the values sent by the other participants are equal to determine (with a high probability) whether they were computed from the same $x$ value.